# automate change in python file and save with different filename

Tags: python, python-2.7, automation

i have a python file named `file_1.py`

```
it has some code in which, i just have to change a word "file_1" to "file_2"
```

and also preserve indentation of other functions`

```
and save it as file_2.py
```

there are 3 occurances of the word file_1

```
i have to do this for 100 such times. `file_1.py, file_2.py.....file_100.py`
```

is there any way to automate this?

Comment: Yes, there's a way to automate it: write code that will load the file, modify the content and save the file with a new name.

Comment: will there be single occurrence of word "file_1" ?

Comment: @mpf82 yes sir, for .txt it  is available, but i have to preserve the indentations too since it is a python file

Comment: This seems like an odd way to go about things. Can you not change your code in file_1.py so that it uses "file_1" as an input, and then maintain one .py script file that you feed with different inputs?

Comment: @RajDamani there are 3 occurances of the word file_1

Comment: @asongtoruin yes sir, but i really want to do it in this way, to create 100 such .py files,, any leads/?

Comment: **Why** do you want to create 100 files like this? That's a _very_ messy approach.

Comment: And please clean up your question. You've been a member long enough to know that a good SO question doesn't look like that. And if you _really_ want to do this crazy file modification thing, you should post your own attempt at coding this, preferably a [mcve] with some sample input.

Answer (score 0):

Run this script:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.FileInput('file_1.py', inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace('file_1', 'file_2'), end='')
```

hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

create a script:

first: read file

```
with open("./file1.py") as f:
    content = f.read()
```

second: replace filename

```
new_content = content.replace("file1","file2")
```

third: write new file(I would suggest you write a new file)

```
with open("./file2.py", "w") as f:
    f.write(new_content)
```

if you have multiple files, use something like

```
filenames = ["file" + str(item) for item in range(1,100)]
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename + ".py") as f:
        content = f.read()
    new_filename = filename[:-1] + str(int(filename[-1]) + 1)
    new_content = content.replace(filename,new_filename)
    with open("./another_folder" + new_filename + ".py", "w") as f:
        f.write(new_content)
```

Comment: didn't understand the last line of your code `filenames = ["file" + str(item) for item in range(1,100)]`  how do you loop it?